# phone webbrowser.navigate not navigating to url

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm in the process of doing my first tutorial for windows phone. I've downloaded the sdk and updates. I'm following the tutorial below.

[tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/02/23/how-to-create-a-mini-browser-application-for-windows-phone-7.aspx)

when i compile and click debug, the emulator fires up and the UI is displayed correctly. The problem is when i click on the "Go" button, nothing happens. The app should display the url that is in the textbox above.

Has anyone any ideas why, sorry if it's obvious but i've started learning this today from an android background.

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    ' Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub url_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles url.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Go_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim site As String

        site = URL.Text

        MiniBrowser.Navigate(New Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute))

    End Sub
End Class
```

.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="MiniBrowser.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY FIRST APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Mini Browser" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="URL" Margin="0,0,120,0" Text="http://www.xbox.com" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="Go" Content="Go" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="MiniBrowser" Margin="0,84,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh very basic mistake :(

You forgot to assign the Click event handler for the Button

```
<Button x:Name="Go" Content="Go" Click="Go_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Comment: hey thanks, sorry i've never even looked at any vb yet, i was just following a tutorial to make sure the sdk and ide is set up correctly. I'll check the tut again. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing happening though i have the event with GO button, below is the code

### XAML

```
        <Button x:Name="Go" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="346,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Go_Click"/>
```

### CS

private void Go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
    {
        //string site = URL.Text;
        //MiniBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
        string site = URL.Text;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(site)) return;
        if (!site.StartsWith("http://") && !site.StartsWith("https://"))
            site = "http://" + site;
        MiniBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```